# Java - Function not returning modified variable

Tags: java, function, return, return-value

I am new to programming and having trouble returning a desired result from a function. The result passed back is always the initialized variable that was passed in.

I have tried several different ways of declaring, changing variable names, and creating static member variables.

There is a problem with my syntax for sure, and I could use help in locating it.

Thanks is advance.

```
package chapter4;

public class FunctionDieRoll {
    static int dieOne;
    static int dieTwo;
    static int totalRoll;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        numRolls(2);
        System.out.println(totalRoll);

    }

    static int numRolls(int rolls){
        int curRoll = 0;
        while (curRoll != rolls){
            dieOne = (int)(Math.random()*6 + 1);
            dieTwo = (int)(Math.random()*6 + 1);
            curRoll = dieOne + dieTwo;
            totalRoll++;
            System.out.println(curRoll);
            System.out.println(totalRoll);
        }
        return totalRoll;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please note that Javascript is not Java. Your code was not a Javascript snippet.

Answer (score 3):

It's returning but you are not receiving on your end

```
   totalRoll= numRolls(2);
   System.out.println(totalRoll);
```

When you do

```
   totalRoll= numRolls(2);
```

The returned value of function `numRolls()`  assigns back the value to `totalRoll` variable.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Should I always be setting the totalRoll variable like that?

Comment: @TrevorG To see the change back, yes. You should.

Comment: @TrevorG Since totalRoll is static there is no need for assigning the result of the call to numRolls, since totalRoll is set in that function.